# Order Trello lists by label

Tags: trello, trello-labels

We use labels to assign a priority to our cards.  Red = High, Yellow = Medium, Blue = Low.  Cards are placed on the list in any order.  Is there a way to re-order the list by the labels?  I know that I can filter the items by the label but that makes all other items on the list disappear.  I may need to change the priority of something but I need to understand all the items in the list to be able to accomplish that.

Current Trello List

- Card 1:Red
- Card 2:Blue
- Card 3:Red
- Card 4:Yellow
- Card 5:Yellow
- Card 6:Red
- Card 7:Blue

Ordered Trello List (Order by Red, Yellow, Blue)

- Card 1:Red
- Card 3:Red
- Card 6:Red
- Card 4:Yellow
- Card 5:Yellow
- Card 2:Blue
- Card 7:Blue

Answer (score 2):

Sorting by labels is not currently possible. This feature has >1k votes on the development board ideas list. I don't seem to be able to link to the card at the moment.

Comment: You're looking for https://trello.com/c/VWrInnH8

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered the Chrome Extension  [Ultimello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm) for Trello.

[image]

A big bonus is that it can do this in a UI only way so it won't save the order for everyone. You can also apply the sorting (it take a bit to do so).

Trello outlines their development thoughts of this as a feature [here](https://trello.com/c/YwKCp0KW/1-sorting-a-list-by-vote-date-label-alphabetically-etc).